# Why I can access my website at (ip address):port but not (domain name):port?

Tags: node.js, apache, amazon-ec2, port, cloudflare

I have an Amazon EC2 instance running with an elastic IP 12.34.56.78. I own a domain name example.com which I've set up to point to the EC2 instance. I'm running an Apache web server on my EC2 instance on port 80, and I can see the website when I visit both http:// 12.34.56.78 and http:// example.com.

I'm also running a node.js server on port 3000. I can see the nodejs page when I visit http:// 12.34.56.78:3000, but not when I visit http:// example.com:3000. My EC2 instance's security group   allows TCP/UDP on port 80, 443, and 3000. Why can't I see my node.js page when I visit my site via its domain name? (I want to run one Apache server and one node.js server)

I think I'm having this problem because I'm using cloudflare to link http:// example.com with 12.34.56.78. But even when I try to connect with http:// direct.example.com:3000, I cannot see my node.js server. (the direct subdomain is supposed to go straight to 12.34.56.78 with no work done by cloudflare)

Any ideas?

Comment: what is the output of `nslookup` / `dig` (Linux-based only) of the domain ?

Comment: I get back the IP addresses of cloudflare's nameservers. 108.162.199.15 and 108.162.198.15. I get the same IPs when I run dig on direct.example.com

Comment: I looked into it and cloudflare only routes traffic on certain ports, so I tried running the node.js server on one of those other ports. It works! Thanks.

Comment: Just 2 penny here: check out Route53 if this fits your domain management needs. Which is within Amazon services list. It will allow you to point domain in a classic way: A Records, and it will work straight away.
Btw, you can proxy your node through Apache as well, so by going to: http://node.example.com/ Apache can proxy to 127.0.0.1:3000 so that way you don't need to provide IP in url as well.
As well if your situation allows you - check out nginx, as it is more friendly in terms of configure and proxying, and works better with node.

Answer (score 2):

you can't, because if you pass your domain through cloudflare by clicking cloud-image, your port will be only available like this :

For requests made via HTTP (all domains on CloudFlare):

80
8080
8880
2052
2082
2086
2095

For requests made via HTTPS (only domains subscribed to Pro, Business, or Enterprise):

443
2053
2083
2087
2096
8443

my solution is create one sub-domain that not pass through cloudflare for any instance like ssh, python etc.

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169156-Which-ports-will-CloudFlare-work-with-